# Obtener un string a partir de un Array

Tags: javascript

Tengo que obtener el nombre por consola de la persona que tenga la edad más pequeña. He conseguido sacar la edad más pequeña a partir del Array, pero no se como sacar el nombre que corresponda a la edad mas pequeña.

```
const estudiant1 = {
    nom: "Lluís",
    edat: 32
};
const estudiant2 = {
    nom: "Kenneth",
    edat: 31
};
const estudiant3 = {
    nom: "Bernat",
    edat: 30
};
    
var edat = [estudiant1.edat,estudiant2.edat,estudiant3.edat]
var q = edat[0];

for (var i = 0; i < edat.length ; i++) {
    if (edat[i] < q) {
    q = edat[i];
    }
}

console.log('Valor mínimo: ' + q);
```

Answer (score 0):

Si guardas el índice de la edad, tendrás el indice del nombre.
Personalmente no estructuraría los datos así, pero voy a poner un ejemplo con tu código.

```js
const estudiant1 = {
    nom: "Lluís",
    edat: 32
};
const estudiant2 = {
    nom: "Kenneth",
    edat: 31
};
const estudiant3 = {
    nom: "Bernat",
    edat: 30
};
    
var edat = [estudiant1.edat,estudiant2.edat,estudiant3.edat]
var q = edat[0];
var index;

for (var i = 0; i < edat.length ; i++) {
    if (edat[i] < q) {
    q = edat[i];
    index=i;
    }
}

var nom;
switch (index) {
    case 0:
        nom=estudiant1.nom;
    break;
    case 1:
        nom=estudiant2.nom;
    break;
    case 2:
        nom=estudiant3.nom;
    break;
}
console.log('Valor mínimo: ' + q);
console.log('Nombre: ' + nom);
```

Personalmente pondría los estudiantes en una matriz en vez de en variables distintas.
Por ejemplo

```js
const estudiants = [
  { nom: "Lluís", edat: 32},
  { nom: "Kenneth", edat: 31},
  { nom: "Bernat", edat: 30}
];

var estudiant_menor=0;

for (var i = 1; i < estudiants.length ; i++) {
  if (estudiants[i].edat < estudiants[estudiant_menor].edat) {
    estudiant_menor = i;
  }
}

console.log('Valor mínimo: ' + estudiants[estudiant_menor].edat);
console.log('Nombre: ' + estudiants[estudiant_menor].nom);
```

Fíjate que el bucle lo inicio en 1, porque el 0 ya empieza siendo el estudiante menor.

Comment: La linea " if (estudiants[i].edat < estudiants[estudiant_menor].edat) {" simplemente identifica el numero mas pequeño o hace una comparacion entre todos?

Comment: Entiendo que inicia con el 32 y hace una comparacion con el 31, ve que no es mas pequeño y luego va a buscar el 30,no?

Comment: En el bucle for, recorre los estudiantes desde el 1 hasta el final, y los compara uno a uno con el menor guardado, y lo reemplaza si es menor.
Así que si, primero  guarda un 0 (primera posicion del array, donde edad vale 32), y compara el 32 con el 31, y guarda el 1 (la posicion del array en que edad es 31) por ser menor,  y después compara con el 30, y guarda el 2 (la posicion del array en que el edad vale 30)  por ser menor.

Comment: Por cierto, viendo que eres compañero de estudio (guiño guiño, codazo codazo), entiendo que se espera que unas las tuplas en una tabla y trabajes con la tabla (como has hecho), no que modifiques la estructura de tuplas que viene dada, aunque tuviera mas sentido.

Comment: compañero giño giño jajajajajajja. Espero que te saliera bien el ejercicio

Answer (score 0):

Esa es la respuesta si lo que busca tiene que tener esta estructura, pero **estoy de acuerdo con la respuesta anterior que tiene la estructuración optimizada.**

```
const estudiant1 = {
nom: "Lluís",
edat: 32
};
const estudiant2 = {
    nom: "Kenneth",
    edat: 31
};
const estudiant3 = {
    nom: "Bernat",
    edat: 30
};

var edat = [estudiant1.edat,estudiant2.edat,estudiant3.edat];
var q = edat[0];

var nom = [estudiant1.nom,estudiant2.nom,estudiant3.nom];
var n = nom[0];

for (var i = 0; i < edat.length ; i++) {
    if (edat[i] < q) {
        q = edat[i];
        n = nom[i];
    }
}

console.log('Valor mínimo: ' + q + " Nombre: " + n );
```